# C# Auto-Implemented Properties - Using Inside Class

Tags: c#

I'm looking for advice on best practices when using Auto-Implemented Properties.

I always use them if I don't need to refer to the property inside the class. However, I'm in the habit of manually adding the private property if I do need to access the property inside the class.

For example, if I had a class named Person with firstName and lastName properties and I never had to manipulate that data inside the class I would just do this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
}
```

However, if I needed to do something with those properties I do this:

```
public class Person
{
    private string _firstName;
    public string firstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { _firstName = value; }
    }

    private string _lastName;
    public string lastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set { _lastName = value; }
    }

    public void testMethod()
    {
        Debug.Print(_firstName + " " + _lastName);
    }

}
```

My question: Is this good practice?

Comment: you should be able to directly use the properties within the class

Comment: What is your reasoning here? Why not just use the auto-properties inside the class? Are you concerned about performance?

Comment: If you want to override properties, declare the property you want to override using the "virtual" keyword

Comment: @GrahamS Yes. I'd reasoned that accessing the public property means that the programme would then have to go through the getter for the internal property. I was thinking, why do this when I can access it directly?

Comment: I'd say that if your program is so time-critical that the extra deref required for properties is a performance concern, then you probably shouldn't be using C# to start with!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's pointless. You should move to fully implemented properties when you need to do more than just setting/getting a backing field.

As things stand:

```
Debug.Print(FirstName + " " + LastName); //convention says use UpperCamel for props
```

would be absolutely fine and introducing a backing-field just introduces unnecessary noise to your code.

If, instead, you want to do some validation:

```
public string LastName
{
    get { return _lastName; }
    set { 
        if(value.Contains("!")){
            throw new Exception("names can't contain '!'");
        }
        _lastName = value; }
}
```

Now you have a valid reason to move away from auto-implemented properties.

If you are simply trying to avoid the overhead of a second lookup, don't worry about it. Chances are that this will never cause performance issues, and if it does, you'll find out through measuring code timings. Trying to write optimally efficient code at the expense of clarity is a bad goal and leads to crufty code. Favour clarity every time, and when your program runs slow, you can go back and find out what caused it. Research has established that there's an extremely high chance that it won't be what you expected, so it's not an economical pursuit trying to guess.

Comment: Exactly, also it looks weird when you get value and assign it directly.

Comment: Agree that simple, clear, readable code is a much more important goal than premature optimisation. Remember that having two different ways to set the value could lead to confusion later.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the responses spender and @GrahamS. I doubt performance on this matter will ever be an actual issue. It was mostly the principal of it. It felt like an extra step. I take the point on clarity. And the point re JITter answers what I was getting at to start with. It's disappointing that some see fit to vote down this question. It was, after all, a question, not a recommendation, and voting down discourages people from asking such questions and learning to code better.

Comment: @Sparked I deleted the point about the JITter because I'm not sure. Needs more research.

Comment: @Sparked not sure why it got down voted. Seems like a reasonable question to me. I've had the same thought process myself.